# Alpha is changed when the button is pressed ios

Tags: ios, swift

I am pretty new to iOS development and I have a question. I have a simple [quiz app](https://github.com/appbrewery/Quizzler-iOS13) and I notice that by default when I press a button the opacity is changing. If I print `sender.alpha` in an IBAction (Touch down) I get 1.0 but while the button is pressed the opacity seems to be reduced to 0.5.  If I try to change alpha in the IBAction (Touch Down) to 1 there is no change (still the opacity seems to be reduced to 0.5) but if I change alpha to 0.001 the opacity is changed to my value.

Can you explain this to me?

Thx!

Comment: are you able to post any screenshots of the problem? Also any code you may think is related to the issue.. that would be helpful to the community in answering your questions

Comment: First question: the default behavior of a `UIButton` is to fade the title label's alpha to 0.2 and then back to 1.0. This is what everyone expects of a button. Why do you want to change that? Or, do you mean you are tapping the button and it changes it's `.alpha` for the ***whole button** and does not return to normal? If so, you must have done something else to it already...

Comment: @DonMag that's it! Thx! I don't want to change that, I was only curious about that because I didn't saw any code where alpha is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the UIButton it state is changed to highlighted when it's clicked.
UIButton has different states such as selected, normal, highlighted and more.